# The problem of sampling with replacement.

Tags: probability

The probability of picking each ball at least once after the x-th draw, where there are n balls in a box and m balls are drawn with replacement each time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is there a question here?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag, which is for questions “solely about the modern theoretical footing for probability”. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.